# The hue parameter in searborn.pairplot() does not work

Tags: python, seaborn, pairplot

everybody. I'm trying to plot a pair plot of the IRIS dataset using searborn. To do this, I load the dataset as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
```

the dataset has four numerical features and one categorical class called variety (with 3 categories). I use the following simple code to pairplot my data:

```
import searborn as sns
sns.pairplot(iris, hue = iris['variety'])
```

But the code returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is there anything that I missed? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `hue` only corresponds to the name of the variable inside pandas.

Hence, the correct code is:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(iris, hue = 'variety')
```

As you can see, the only change is that we provide `hue='variety'` instead of the array itself (`hue=iris['variety']`).

Source:

Seaborn documentation, `pairplot` function.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html